# CSS hide item from list using the name

Tags: css

I've never worked with CSS before (I am a WordPress user). But I think I'm very close, but cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong.

So, I have this list `<li>` item that I want to hide. I tried using the n'th child, but that did not work, as the order of the list can change depending on if the field is filled or not. So, I need to use a data selector. I tried this:

```
.atbd_listing_data_list {
li[data-value="Breed : "]
    visibility: hidden;}
```

But that did not work. This is the code where it's coming from:

```html
<div class="atbd_listing_data_list">
  <ul>
    <li>Pedigree: Fly x Hors la loi II x Concorde</li>
    <li>Competition height: </li>
    <li>Age Category: </li>
    <li>Age: 15</li>
    <li>Color: </li>
    <li>Height: </li>
    <li>Studbook: </li>
    <li>Gender: </li>
    <li>Breed: </li>
    <li>
      <p><span class="la la-clock-o"></span>October 25, 2020
      </p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I simply want to hide the Breed and Age Category fields, but I have been trying for a couple of hours now without success.

Anybody wants to teach me some CSS and how to handle this :) ? I think I'm almost there, must be a small error that I'm making.

Kind regards,

Collin

Comment: You can hide them using `.atbd_listing_data_list ul li:nth-child(8), .atbd_listing_data_list ul li:nth-child(9) { display: none; }` But there are ways through WordPress as well. CSS's method can actually hide other elements when order is changed.

Answer (score 0):

**This answer assumes you are not capable of editing the files generating or template of the list.**

Well, to be fair, these CSS rules are more "hacking" your way into a result instead of actual fixing a problem. But I can understand where you are coming from. There should be another way to solve the problem without hiding the data.

You are on the right path, `:nth-child` selectors is great for hiding something for a "static list" (nth-child count from a current point, if this list is shorter, other data will hide instead).

The `[data-value="breed"]` will only work when `<li data-value="breed">` is the element. It's not a "data contains value" kind of selector.

```css
.atbd_listing_data_list ul li:nth-child(3),
.atbd_listing_data_list ul li:nth-child(9) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="atbd_listing_data_list">
  <ul>
    <li>Pedigree: Fly x Hors la loi II x Concorde</li>
    <li>Competition height: </li>
    <li>Age Category: </li>
    <li>Age: 15</li>
    <li>Color: </li>
    <li>Height: </li>
    <li>Studbook: </li>
    <li>Gender: </li>
    <li>Breed: </li>
    <li>
      <p><span class="la la-clock-o"></span>October 25, 2020
      </p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the data attribute to the li you want to hide then select it as shown in example.

```css
li[data-value="hide"] {
    display: none; 
  }
```

```html
<div class="atbd_listing_data_list">
  <ul>
    <li>Pedigree: Fly x Hors la loi II x Concorde</li>
    <li>Competition height: </li>
    <li>Age Category: </li>
    <li>Age: 15</li>
    <li>Color: </li>
    <li>Height: </li>
    <li>Studbook: </li>
    <li>Gender: </li>
    <li data-value="hide">Breed: </li>
    <li>
      <p><span class="la la-clock-o"></span>October 25, 2020
      </p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```